# How do I line up the texts at the same height?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a 3-column thing where you can display an image with few line of texts under it.
The problem that I'm currently having is that if there is 1 line where the text is not a single line, then the whole thing won't be aligned (as shown in the pictures, it's either the first column is not aligned with the other 2 or vice versa).

So I'm wondering what can I do here to align all the 4 line of texts even if some are single line of text and others are longer?

Laptop view:
[image]

Desktop view:
[image: problem]

```css
.aboutcount .whitecircle {
    width: 23%;
    margin: 30px 1%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

.countimg {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.whitecircle {
    text-align: center;
}

.whitecircle h3 {
    font-size: 3.5em;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 0;
    color: #2d3689;
}

.whitecircle h3 sub {
    font-size: .3em;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

.whitecircle h4 {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.whitecircle-sub {
    color: #2d3689;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.whitecircle .sub-text {
    font-size: .3em;
}
```

```html
<div class="row aboutcount">
<div class="whitecircle">
<div class="countimg"><img src="http://44.236.201.82/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/CAPITALIZACAO-DE-MERCADO-DE.png"></div>
<h4>CAPITALIZAÇÃO DE MERCADO DE</h4><span class="whitecircle-sub">MALAYSIAN RINGGIT</span>
<h3>56.6<span class="sub-text"> Bilhão</span></h3>
<h6>(COMO EM 2 FEBRUARY 2021)</h6></div>

<div class="whitecircle">
<div class="countimg"><img src="http://44.236.201.82/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/FUNDO-DE-ACIONISTAS-DA.png"></div>
<h4>FUNDO DE ACIONISTAS DA</h4><span class="whitecircle-sub">MALAYSIAN RINGGIT</span>
<h3>2.6<span class="sub-text"> Bilhão</span></h3>
<h6>(COMO EM 19 MARCH 2020)</h6></div>

<div class="whitecircle">
<div class="countimg"><img src="http://44.236.201.82/wp-content/uploads/2021/04/RECEITA.png"></div>
<h4>RECEITA</h4><span class="whitecircle-sub">MALAYSIAN RINGGIT</span>
<h3>2.4<span class="sub-text"> Bilhão</span></h3>
<h6>(COMO EM 19 MARCH 2020)</h6></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just add height in h4 tag and it works. Remove img style when you put your own image

```css
.aboutcount .whitecircle {
    width: 23%;
    margin: 30px 1%;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}

.countimg {
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
  
}

.whitecircle {
    text-align: center;
}

.whitecircle h3 {
    font-size: 3.5em;
    font-weight: 600;
    padding: 0;
    color: #2d3689;
}

.whitecircle h3 sub {
    font-size: .3em;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

.whitecircle h4 {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
        height: 15px;
}

.whitecircle-sub {
    color: #2d3689;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.whitecircle .sub-text {
    font-size: .3em;
}

img{
width:150px
}
```

```html
<div class="row aboutcount">
<div class="whitecircle">
<div class="countimg"><img src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/circle/circle_PNG33.png"></div>
<h4>CAPITALIZAÇÃO DE MERCADO DE</h4><span class="whitecircle-sub">MALAYSIAN RINGGIT</span>
<h3>56.6<span class="sub-text"> Bilhão</span></h3>
<h6>(COMO EM 2 FEBRUARY 2021)</h6></div>

<div class="whitecircle">
<div class="countimg"><img src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/circle/circle_PNG33.png"></div>
<h4>FUNDO DE ACIONISTAS DA</h4><span class="whitecircle-sub">MALAYSIAN RINGGIT</span>
<h3>2.6<span class="sub-text"> Bilhão</span></h3>
<h6>(COMO EM 19 MARCH 2020)</h6></div>

<div class="whitecircle">
<div class="countimg"><img src="https://pngimg.com/uploads/circle/circle_PNG33.png"></div>
<h4>RECEITA</h4><span class="whitecircle-sub">MALAYSIAN RINGGIT</span>
<h3>2.4<span class="sub-text"> Bilhão</span></h3>
<h6>(COMO EM 19 MARCH 2020)</h6></div>
</div>
```